# Error while inserting data into Access using Netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans

While creating a connection to Access and trying to insert simple data I get the following error:

```
 run:
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javaapplication1.Authenticate.insertdata(Authenticate.java:49)
at javaapplication1.vendor.actionPerformed(vendor.java:74)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Here's the code snippet if anyone can help a little and look into this. The code 
code compiles fine but gives an error at runtime:

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.sql.*;

public class Authenticate {

    final String fileName = "C:/Users/darksword/Desktopdb.accdb";
    Connection con = null;

    Authenticate()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+fileName;
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        finally
            {
                try { if(con!=null) {con.close();} } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
    }

    void insertdata(String Name,String Address,String ContactNumber,int y) throws SQLException
    {
        String str = Integer.toString(y);
        //Statement st=con.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into product(id,VName,VAddress,VContactNumber) values(?,?,?,?)");
        pstmt.setString(1, str);
        pstmt.setString(1, Name);
        pstmt.setString(1, Address);
        pstmt.setString(1, ContactNumber);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        pstmt.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think it's well formatted code ?

Comment: Are you calling the Authenticate() method anywhere which is initiating your con object ?

Comment: well i cannot format the errors
but i guess code itself is formatted and its a short code
and @sanket i am just calling it 
            Authenticate x;
            x = new Authenticate();
             x.insertdata(Name.getText(),Address.getText(),ContactNumber.getText(),y);

Comment: You seem to be closing your con object in Authenticate(). Check the finally block. Just do a System.out.println(con) in insertdata before you access the con object. Seems like its null / closed.

Comment: yes the connection is null i commented the finally block but its still null

Comment: ok....try and put a System.out.println(con) statement just after --- con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","") in Authenticate(); Check if the connection is null here. In this case your database is not getting connected. Print the exception in the catch block. You will get an idea as to why the con object is null..

Comment: the problem is solved 
i didnt put "/" after desktop silly mistake i guess
but now insert statement is not working
Can u tell me a simple way to insert data

Comment: @stacymalina: *(not an answer hence the comment)* You should really not perform these kind of operation on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). You may want to look into the MVC pattern(s) or, at least, move the DB code outside the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

You're silently catching an exception when establishing the database connection which leaves `con` as `null` should an exception occur. Add

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

to the exception block.

In addition, you close your `Connection` immediately after assigning the variable in the constructor

```
con.close();
```